# Data Format Jquery Ajax Post Cross Domain Call Asp.Net MVC method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying $.ajax post MVC call from http to https cross domain.

**Client Side**

```
enter code here

$.ajax({    
type: 'post',    
crossDomain: true,    
url: 'https://localhost/views/Member/VerifyEmail',    
beforeSend: function () { alert('I am sending'); },    
data: '{name:"John"}',    
dataType: "json",    
success: function (data) { pdata = data; }    
});
```

**Server Side**

```
 [RequireHttps]    
 [HttpPost]    
 public string VerifyEmail(string name){    
   return "got it"
 }
```

I have added Access-Control-Allow-Origin to `web.config` so the call can be established fine. Now the problem is on server side I got variable name = null

I have also checked debugging and found the data has actually been send to server

```
HttpContext.Request.Form    
{%7bname%3a%22hello%22%7d}    
[System.Web.HttpValueCollection]: {%7bname%3a%22hello%22%7d}
```

The question is how I could retrieve it from the web method?

Answer (score 0):

%7bname%3a%22hello%22%7d This is HTML entity String please Decode the String then parse for JSON.

Comment: Hi, would you give me a bit more details that should I do this on server side or client side?

Comment: HttpContext.Request.Form    
{%7bname%3a%22hello%22%7d}    
[System.Web.HttpValueCollection]: {%7bname%3a%22hello%22%7d} what you need to perform is HttpUtility.HtmlDecode and get the decoded string then perform Json Evaluate function on it .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your call to

```
$.ajax({    
 type: 'post',    
 crossDomain: true,    
 url: 'https://localhost/views/Member/VerifyEmail',    
 beforeSend: function () { alert('I am sending'); },    
 data: 'John',    
 dataType: "text",    
 success: function (data) { pdata = data; }    
});
```

Comment: Thanks Asif, yes, I could get the data from HttpContext.Request.Form[0] but this is a bit too strange if I am posting a lot of data especially I want this works for JSON objects

Comment: ok, tried more, I have now been able to get the json data by using FormCollection and then serlizer.Deserialize the formCollection[0]. But this is also strange as why I cannot pass the data to method parameter?

Comment: For working with json you need to create an entity. Just try to create an entity with the property name.